# How do I trigger a "TextChanged" event using tablet pc input panel?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

I am working with a rather complex WPF control; it is a button that, when pressed, creates a Popup, with a TextBox set as the Popup's content. (If it matters, this popup does not seem to be declared in the XAML, but solely within the complex WPF's XAML.CS

I am trying to use this with Window's handwriting recognition software for tablets (installed by default in `Accessories/Tablet PC/Tablet PC Input Panel` on my non-tablet Windows 7 install)

When I click the button, the Textbox appears. Typing anything into the textbox will trigger the textbox's "TextChanged" event. However, if I were to use the Input Panel's handwriting recognition, and press "insert", the TextChanged event of the textbox does not get triggered. (The TextInput event on the ComplexControl, however, *does*)

When I use the Input Panel's "insert" on *regular* WPF Textboxes, it **does** trigger the TextChanged event.

I assume that some complication of the nested controls is making the Input Panel not work as expected in the former case but not in the latter case, but due to my relative inexperience with WPF (heck, the WPF control itself is legacy code!) I'm not entirely certain why the one would trigger and not the other.

Any ideas? I'm not sure what code I could provide that would be most helpful.